# Esperar imagens carregar para serem mostradas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de fazer um sistema que quando a página for solicitada mostrara um GIF de `load` esperando as imagens carregarem, assim que elas carregarem o GIF some e as imagens são mostradas. Alguém sabe como fazer isto?

Comment: Hmm, olha, o que me diz de colocar o gif de loading como background da div onde será carregada a imagem?
Teoricamente quando a imagem carregar ficará por cima do gif.
Pode funcionar...

Answer (score 0):

voce pode usar a função load(); e  fadeOut(); pra fazer a sua div sumir. 
Mais ou menos assim :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Bom espero ter ajudado. 
Abraço

Comment: e depois como faco para ela aparecer quando as imagens estiverem carregadas?